# Include background image using react-material-ui-carousel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, carousel, next.js

I am trying to use a background image in a carousel component, but when I refer to the image as a component, I could not run the development because one character error blocks.
I would like to use some background images with the products I want to expose.

```
export default function Management() {

  var items = [
    {
      name: "Produto #1",
      description: "Oculos esportivo"
    },
    {
      name: "Produto #2",
      description: "Jaqueta Jeans"
    },
    {
      name: "Produto #3",
      description: "Presente para o dia das crianças"
    }
  ]

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Carousel
        autoPlay={"false"}
        animation={"fade"}
      >
        {
          items.map((item, i) => <Item key={i} item={item} />)
        }
      </Carousel >
      <div>
        <h1>managing products</h1>
      </div>

    </Layout>
  )
  function Item(props) {
    return (
      <Paper>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox icon={<FavoriteBorder />} checkedIcon={<Favorite />} name="checkedH" />}
          label="Meu Favorito"
        />
        <Box borderRadius={16} {...defaultProps} >
          <h2>{props.item.name}</h2>
          <p>{props.item.description}</p>

        </Box>
      </Paper>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Banner I found that works as I wanted when I posted it.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
//import './Banner.css';

export default function Banner() {
  return (
    <Carousel
      autoPlay
      infiniteLoop
      showThumbs={false}>
        <div >
          <img alt="banner4" src="assets/leilao4.jpg" />
          <p className="legend">Legend 4</p>
        </div>
        <div >
          <img alt="banner5" src="assets/leilao5.jpg" />
          <p className="legend">Legend 5</p>
        </div>
        <div >
          <img alt="banner4" src="assets/leilao4.jpg" />
          <p className="legend">Legend 4</p>
        </div>
      </Carousel>
  )
}
```